# DataGridView Databinding Display Items in Child List As DataGridViewColumns

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I would like to display each item in property Bars within the class Foo as separate databound DataGridViewColumns.  Currently only the property Name appears as a column when setting the DGV's Datasource.  I want the HeaderText to be the Name property of each Bar, and the cell's value to be the IsValid property.

```
Public Class frmDebugTesting

    Private fooList As New List(Of Foo)

    Private Sub frmDebugTesting_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim foo1 As New Foo
        foo1.Name = "John Doe"

        Dim bar1 As New Bar
        bar1.Name = "Example 1"
        bar1.IsValid = True
        foo1.Bars.Add(bar1)
        Dim bar2 As New Bar
        bar2.Name = "Example 2"
        bar2.IsValid = False
        foo1.Bars.Add(bar2)

        fooList.Add(foo1)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = fooList
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Bar
    Public Property IsValid As Boolean
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Public Class Foo
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Bars As New List(Of Bar)
End Class
```

Comment: Sounds like the Master-Detail idiom.  You probably would not like the result if there were say, 10 detail items per master item.  Users would get confused with which one is which.  Display the child items in their own DGV which gets filtered based on the current Master Item Id

Comment: What you're suggesting is not possible using data-binding. The grid will only display a column for each property or column in the items of the data source. To be specific, it will only display a column for each `PropertyDescriptor`. It's not practical exposing a `PropertyDescriptor` for each item in that list of children because the number of items is variable. You can do it manually if you want but it's not going to happen automatically.